# Не работает dateFormat в mapstruct 1.4.1

Tags: java, mapstruct

При генерации маппинга параметр dateFormat как-будто игнорируется. В реализации set происходит без преобразования даты. Java11.Spring-boot.Lombook.

Описание в мапинга:
`@Mapping(source = "changeDate", target = "changeDate", dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYY")`

Результат генерации:

`cRSBeneficiariesInfo.setChangeDate( beneficiary.getChangeDate());`

Пример dateFormat как  должно быть после генерации.
`(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(areaPO.getUpdatedTime())`
https://www.programmersought.com/article/7108458602/

Сталкивался кто-то с таким?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.
Нужно что бы поле класса было Date. Если String то не работает.